# How to represent the nonlinear model as a state space in Unscented Kalman Filter

Tags: kalman-filters, state-space, self-study

There is an Autoregressive model of order 1 (AR(1)) that is excited by a non-linear signal as the input:
$$x_t = \rho x_{t-1} + u_t \tag{1}$$
The time series $u_t$ is generated from a nonlinear map,
$$u_t = f(u_{t-1},\mathbf{w}) \tag{2}$$ where $f$ is the nonlinear function.
The observations are $$y_t = x_t + v_t \tag{3}$$ where $v_t$ is the measurement noise that is an Additive White Gaussian Noise.

Q1: Can I re-write the model (1) as a state space in the following way:

$$x_t = Ax_{t-1} + f(u_{t-1},\mathbf{w}) $$

$$y_t =  x_t+ v_t \tag{4}$$

Is the above representation correct? If not then I shall be grateful for the correct technique to represent it.

Comment: Does it matter how $u_t$ is generated?  Why are you applying the Unscented KF? What parameters are you interested in estimating?  Your simple substitution probably isn't quite there. You will probably have to include $u$ as part of the state, and then $A$ will instead be a nonlinear operation on $x_{t-1}$ and $u_{t-1}$.

Comment: Not sure if my answer is clear; please comment on it and I'll try to update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than write

$$
x_t = Ax_{t-1} + f(u_{t-1},\mathbf{w})
$$

as the state update equation, I'd write:

$$
\xi = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
x_t\\
u_t 
\end{array}
\right] 
$$

and then
$$
\xi_t = g(\xi_{t-1},A,\mathbf{w})
$$

so that
$$
y_t = \left[ 1\ \ \ 0 \right] \xi_t + v_t
$$

Then you could apply the [non-additive noise formulation of the EKF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Kalman_filter#Non-additive_noise_formulation_and_equations) to get your filter equations.

Comment: The representation makes sense but I am unsure about the non additive part. I need to do augmented state representation so how can I do augmented state representation where the process noise $f$ and the measurement noise are augmented states? $\xi$ appears to be the augmented state for signal state and process noise = $[\mathbf{x^T_{t-1},u_t^T}]$;. Please correct me if wrong

Comment: Well, your output equation is already linear, so you don't need to augment the state for the measurement noise; it's just the process noise that is problematic.  Yes, $\xi$ as above is an augmented state.